# Error when evaluating a Python programming for the Ritcher Scale

Tags: keyerror, python-3.7

I'm viewing logarithms and a view mention that the ritcher scale is logaritmatic so I thought I wonder if someone made one in Python. Which they did but I found one to look at from :http://learnpaithon.blogspot.com/p/earthquake-power-calculator.html, now it's totally possible that it's just not formatted to Python 3.7 but I'm not seeing anything wrong.  When I run it I get this error: print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[0],  Richter_Joules( L[0] ),  Richter_TNT( L[0] ) ))
KeyError: ' '

Here is the code: 
'''Richter Scale Program'''

```
import math 


def Richter_Joules( scale ):
    sum=(1.5*scale)+4.8
    return 10**sum


def Richter_TNT( R_scale ):
    val=Richter_Joules(R_scale)/(4.184*10**9)    # One ton TNT yields 4.184x109 #joules
    return val


L=[1.0,  5.0,  9.0,  9.1,  9.5]



def main( ):
    '''Function for displaying the Richter Scale'''

    print( "Richter       Joules                      TNT" )

    print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[0],  Richter_Joules( L[0] ),  Richter_TNT( L[0] ) ))
    print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[1],  Richter_Joules( L[1] ),  Richter_TNT( L[1] ) ))
    print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[2],  Richter_Joules( L[2] ),    Richter_TNT( L[2] ) ))
    print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[3],  Richter_Joules( L[3] ),    Richter_TNT( L[3] ) ))
    print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[4],   Richter_Joules( L[4] ),    Richter_TNT( L[4] ) ))

    print("\n")


    r=float( input( "Please enter a Richter Scale Value : " ) )

    print( "Richter Scale Value: ", r)
    RJ = Richter_Joules(r)
    RT = Richter_TNT(r)
    print( "Equivalence in joule:", RJ)
    print( "Equivalence in tons of TNT: ", RT)  


main()
```

Are there too many spaces?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the spaces between the braces.  `{ }` should be `{}`

```
for l in L:
    print("{}    {}         {}".format(l,  Richter_Joules(l),  Richter_TNT(l)))
```

This is happening because `format` seems to interpret `{ }` as attempting to lookup the keyword argument `' '`.   So `"{ }".format(**{" ": 1})` will evaluate to `1`.

This is a little surprising because [according to the syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) `arg_name`s should be valid identifiers, which `' '` isn't.

Comment: Ok, so when it was formatting it thought of the space in the {} something to format instead of ignoring it. Gotcha and thanks. That solved the issue.